# Using software Serial for Adafruit Thermal library and more general cpp question

Tags: softwareserial, adafruit, attiny85

I'm working on a proof of concept for using the [Adafruit_Thermal](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Thermal-Printer-Library) printer library with an ATTiny85.

The ATTiny85 does not come with hardware serial capability, so I started looking into using SoftwareSerial to create the serial port necessary. I started down this path and ran into an error in the thermal library's constructor:

```cpp
// thermal-printer.ino example file

#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#define TX_PIN 3
#define RX_PIN 4 


SoftwareSerial mySerial(RX_PIN, TX_PIN);


#include "Adafruit_Thermal.h"

Adafruit_Thermal printer(&mySerial); // Pass addr to printer constructor
```

```cpp
// Adafruit_Thermal.h

class Adafruit_Thermal : public Print
{

public:
    // IMPORTANT: constructor syntax has changed from prior versions
    // of this library.  Please see notes in the example code!

    Adafruit_Thermal(Stream *s = &Serial, uint8_t dtr = 255);
```

> Documents/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_Thermal_Printer_Library/Adafruit_Thermal.h:125:33: error: 'Serial' was not declared in this scope
>      Adafruit_Thermal(Stream *s = &Serial, uint8_t dtr = 255);

If I understand correctly, the verification process is failing because the compiler is looking for a global `Serial` value in the `Adafruit_Thermal.h`file that doesn't exist because the ATTiny85 does not have HardwareSerial.

But, going by the Adafruit_Thermal class' constructor signature the reference passing of `Serial` is just a default value (right?) so I should be able to remove it and pass in my software serial reference. [The `SoftwareSerial` class inherits from `Stream`](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src/SoftwareSerial.h), so it should still be a valid reference pass:

```cpp
// this:
Adafruit_Thermal(Stream *s = &Serial, uint8_t dtr = 255);

// changes to this:
Adafruit_Thermal(Stream *s, uint8_t dtr = 255);
```

But when I do that, I start getting verification errors that make it look like the thermal instance wasn't constructed, like:

> undefined reference to `Adafruit_Thermal::begin(unsigned char)'

and

> undefined reference to `Adafruit_Thermal::Adafruit_Thermal(Stream*, unsigned char)'

Does this mean the class isn't getting constructed?

I looked at the underlying constructor definition to see if something was blowing up in there, but there doesn't seem to be anything fancy at the constructor level:

```cpp
// Constructor
Adafruit_Thermal::Adafruit_Thermal(Stream *s, uint8_t dtr) :
  stream(s), dtrPin(dtr) {
  dtrEnabled = false;
}
```

This should still work with the software serial reference pass, right?

I'm a bit lost on how to debug this now. Any ideas?

## Update

After a reply from Majenko I pulled up the cpp file and looked at the header reference:

[image: header reference]

So this means the cpp file was still referring to the include path header file instead of the `lib` version?

I updated my cpp file to use:

```
#include "lib/Adafruit_Thermal.h"
```

and I still get undefined reference errors, so it may still be something else, but I wanted to share this additional info.

Comment: On the face of it, removing `= &Serial` is exactly what you want to do, and behaves exactly as you expect. I suspect the other errors you are now getting are unrelated.

Comment: Ah ok. I'll keep digging then. If I figure out exactly what was happening I'll post back. Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: It looks like the IDE might not be compiling the .cpp file from the library.

Comment: OH! Holy cow I totally didn't think of that! I'm adding an update to show a screen shot.

Comment: What IDE is that then?

Comment: Ah, this is VSCode (https://code.visualstudio.com) using the arduino extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.vscode-arduino). I'm a web app dev and I already had vscode set up the way I wanted, so switching to the arduino IDE was rough. Luckily the arduino extension allows for doing pretty much everything you'd want to do in the arduino IDE in vscode instead :)

Comment: Ah. So is there something you have to do in that IDE to say "Include the files in `lib` in the compilation`?

Comment: Your last comment helped me figure it out. I posted a detailed explanation in the answers section. Thanks for your help @Majenko

Answer (score 2):

:'( it's a bitter sweet solution.

After @majenko's last comment:

> Ah. So is there something you have to do in that IDE to say "Include the files in lib in the compilation`?

I remembered that this issue has bitten me before. Specifically, the issue of including subfolders into a sketch.

Normally in programming languages (at least all of the ones I work in normally), you can use relative paths or namespaces to include files from subfolders, but for some reason with Arduino if you want to include files from subfolders **you have to put the files in a directory named `src`**.

And it specifically needs to be `src`. You can't use `lib` or `libs` or `source` or `whatevernameyouwant`, it needs to be src.

I can't find a spot in the arduino reference docs or the IDE's github repository that explains that you need to use `src` for the subfolder name, but you can find various mentions in the forums. E.g.

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/54655/35534

So yeah, the solution to my problem was three parts.

1. Adopting the `Adafruit_Thermal` library into my codebase so that I could edit the source code without worrying about those changes polluting the orginal.
2. Removing the `&Serial` reference pass in the constructor declaration of `Adafruit_Thermal.h`
3. using the `src` directory name to include things from a subfolder.

[image: solution structure]

After doing this, the sketch passes verification.

But here's the bittersweet part. After getting past all of this and seeing the compiler get past the sketch verification the bombshell dropped; the sketch is too big for the attiny:

[image: heartbreak]

I guess it was not meant to be :'(

Well, at least I know what was causing the linker/compiler errors and I'll be able to sleep at night :P

Thanks for your help Majenko :bows:.